# How do you make a custom calendar in python?

Tags: python, calendar

To my understanding, you can make a text calendar with

```
import calendar
cal = calendar.setfirstweekday(startday)
cal = calendar.prmonth(year,month)
```

although, this creates a `calendar` for that `month` and `year`.

My problem arises when I want to make a custom `Calendar`, that starts on a specific day of the week, and you can choose how many days are in the month. How would you accomplish this?

Comment: This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188656/print-month-using-the-month-and-day

Answer (score 0):

One way to start this is by creating a dictionary that defines the different elements of a given month: a string for the name and range() for the amount of days in the month. This would not require the import calendar.